# IAM CloudFormation Templates AWS Roles

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam, amazon-policy

So if I were to create a federated developer role for developers (duh) and push it to AWS in the form of a cf template, the role's name is simply what I named it. But for some reason, if the role is designed for AWS services/resources to assume (say, a Lambda role for EC2 instances), the role has a seemingly random string of 12 characters appended to it.

Ex: iam-lam-role-85C94J38RDE2

Why does CloudFormation append this automatically?

Comment: can you show your CloudFormation template? Do you set the RoleName property in both cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the [Name Type](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-name.html) section of the CloudFormation documentation:

> By default, AWS CloudFormation generates a unique physical ID to name a resource. For example, AWS CloudFormation might name an Amazon S3 bucket with the following physical ID `stack123123123123-s3bucket-abcdefghijk1`. [...]
>
> If you want to use a custom name, specify a name property for that resource in your AWS CloudFormation template.

For [`AWS::IAM::Role`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-role.html) (which is one of the [resources that supports custom names](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-name.html#d0e147837)), specify the [`RoleName`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-role.html#cfn-iam-role-rolename) property to provide a custom name.

Your question suggests that the default physical ID actually changes based on the contents of the [`AssumeRolePolicyDocument`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-role.html#cfn-iam-role-assumerolepolicydocument) property within the `AWS::IAM::Role` resource. I haven't observed any such behavior in practice, so I think it's likely you specified a `RoleName` for one resource and not the other.

Answer (score 1):

CloudFormation appends random characters to the physical ID so there won't be name collisions between 2 IAM roles. In a given AWS account, there cannot be 2 IAM roles with the same name.

If you were to create 2 CloudFormation stacks that each contain an IAM role with the same logical ID (e.g. `MyRole`), there would be name collisions for the IAM roles created. That's why CloudFormation generates a random name for your IAM roles (e.g. `MyRole-85C94J38RDE2` and `MyRole-78DM29SKFJD8`).

If you want to assign a fixed name for your IAM roles, you can use [the `RoleName` property](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-role.html#cfn-iam-role-rolename).